# Visual Studio Solution Explorer extension to rename file but NOT extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, solution-explorer

Windows Explorer has a small (but great!) feature that Visual Studio does not:

When you rename a file in Windows Explorer on Windows 7 (for sure, I think for Vista and later) it selects only the main part of the filename, and not the file extension. It makes the assumption that 90% of the time, you don't want to change the file extension and saves you from the choice of using the mouse to select the relevant part to rename (bad) or having to retype the file extension (also bad).

Of course this is only if you have file extensions displayed in Windows Explorer, but if you're browsing Stack Overflow I would make an educated guess you're in the "Show me the extensions" camp.

Is there an extension for Visual Studio that provides this same functionality? Extensions seem to be getting longer and longer. Today we have `.cshtml` at 7 characters, who knows what we will have in the future.

As of this writing, I am talking about an extension for Visual Studio 2010. I have not gotten to play with the Visual Studio 2012 Release Candidate yet, so if this feature is baked in there I would accept assurances that I'll get it when I upgrade as an answer as well.

Comment: This feature does exist in the Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski do you know if this is a setting? It used to act this way for me, but lately it's been selecting the whole file name for me. I'm not sure if a setting got switched somewhere

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, and comment sections aren't places to ask follow-up questions. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the current behavior of Visual Studio, and has been for a while, so when you press F2 to rename a file in the solution explorer it will highlight the name without the extension.

However, today I noticed it started selecting the whole file with extension, like mentioned by @DLeh in the comments. Turns out it was related to a specific project, so to me the solution was to delete the `.vs` folder, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001305/file-rename-in-solution-explorer-vs-2015#38604289).